# Setting timeout on Android Restlet client

Tags: android, client, restlet

I'm currently working on an android client app that needs to communicate with a server through a rest interface. To assist in this, I'm using the restlet-android 2.1.2 framework.

As it currently stands, when everything works everything is fine but if I the server for instance goes down or I try to connect to the wrong url I would expect the client to timeout and would like to do so fairly quickly. But it seems that any default timeout is very long indeed and how one would go about changing it is not very clear. I have tried creating a Client object with a HttpClientHelper and setting the clients contexts timeout parameters (as desribed here http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.1/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/httpclient/HttpClientHelper.html) and passing said context into my ClientResources upon their creation. Though none if it makes any sort of difference.